# Validation does not work with PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am having problem to see the problem with a pre-scripted template.
There are 3 files as follows,

```
/contact.php
/forms/contact.php
/js/forms.js
```

So when a visitor fills up the contact.php in root directory it redirects to /forms/contact.php and forms.js checks the form and if there is no problem sends an email.

Here is my /contact.php which includes the form,

```
<form id="contactform" method="post" action="forms/contact.php">
<div class="divide10"></div>
<input id="name" name="name" value="Your Name" type="text" class="prepared-input">
<div class="divide15"></div>
<input id="email" name="email" value="Your Email" type="text" class="prepared-input">
<div class="divide15"></div>
<textarea  id="contactmessage" name="message" rows="3" class="prepared-input">Your Message</textarea>
<div class="divide15"></div>
<input type="submit" id="From_Comment_Go" value="Send Message " class="btn maincolor small">
<span class="errormessage   hiddenatstart">Error! Please correct marked fields.</span>
<span class="successmessage   hiddenatstart">Message send successfully!</span>
<span class="sendingmessage   hiddenatstart">Sending...</span>
</form>
```

Here is my /forms/contact.php

```
<?php
$to = 'example@mail.com';


//Language Options
$contact_labelmailhead = 'Contact Form Email';
$contact_labelmailsubject = 'Contact Form Email from';
$contact_labelname = 'Name';
$contact_labelemail = 'Email';
$contact_labelmessage = 'Message';

$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$email = trim($_POST['email']);
$message = str_replace(chr(10), "<br>", $_POST['message']);

$body = "<html><head><title>$contact_labelmailhead</title></head><body><br>";
$body .= "$contact_labelname: <b>" . $name . "</b><br>";
$body .= "$contact_labelemail <b>" . $email . "</b><br>";
$body .= "$contact_labelmessage:<br><hr><br><b>" . $message . "</b><br>";
$body .= "<br></body></html>";

$subject = $contact_labelmailsubject.' ' . $name;
$header = "From: $email\n" . "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";

mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);


?>
```

and lastly forms.js is here,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    /* Contact Form */
    if(jQuery('#contactform').length != 0){
        addForm('#contactform');
    }

    /* Quick Contact */
    if(jQuery('#quickcontact').length != 0){
        addForm('#quickcontact');
    }

    /* Blog Comments */
    if(jQuery('#replyform').length != 0){
        addForm('#replyform');
    }
});

    function addForm(formtype) {
    var formid = jQuery(formtype);
    var emailsend = false;

    formid.find("input[type=submit]").click(sendemail);


    function validator() {

        var emailcheck = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
        var othercheck = /.{4}/;
        var noerror = true;

        formid.find(".requiredfield").each(function () {

            var fieldname = jQuery(this).attr('name');
            var value = jQuery(this).val();
            if(value == "Name *" || value == "Email *" || value == "Message *"){
                value = ""; 
            }

            if(fieldname == "email"){
                if (!emailcheck.test(value)) {
                    jQuery(this).addClass("formerror");
                    noerror = false;
                } else {
                    jQuery(this).removeClass("formerror");
                }   
            }else{
                if (!othercheck.test(value)) {
                    jQuery(this).addClass("formerror");
                    noerror = false;
                } else {
                    jQuery(this).removeClass("formerror");
                }   
            }
        })

        if(!noerror){
            formid.find(".errormessage").fadeIn();
        }

        return noerror;
    }

    function resetform() {
        formid.find("input").each(function () {
            if(!jQuery(this).hasClass("button")) jQuery(this).val("");  
        })
        formid.find("textarea").val("");
        emailsend = false;
    }


    function sendemail() {
        formid.find(".successmessage").hide();
        var phpfile = "";
        if(formtype=="#contactform"){
            phpfile = "forms/contact.php";
        }else if(formtype.lastIndexOf("c_")){
            phpfile = "forms/quickcontact.php";
        }else{
            phpfile = "";
        }
        if (validator()) {
            if(!emailsend){
                emailsend = true;
                formid.find(".errormessage").hide();
                formid.find(".sendingmessage").show();
                jQuery.post(phpfile, formid.serialize(), function() {
                    formid.find(".sendingmessage").hide();
                    formid.find(".successmessage").fadeIn();
                    if(!formtype.lastIndexOf("c_"))resetform();
                });
            }
        } 
        return false
    }
```

}

So, leaving the form sends Values :S and does not check anything. Shall I try to fix this or try to implement something else? I am not that into jQuery and cannot say if there is something wrong with validation script.

Some advice would be great!
Thank you!

Comment: Are you only validating data on the client side (with javascript), you should `ALWAYS` validate on the server, I can simply disable javascript on my browser and pass anything to your server (thats where I should be stopped through validation)

Answer (score 0):

There are errors on .js syntax, this could stop some js code from being called. First of all, fix these errors in js like this:

```
formid.find("input").each(function ()
{
    if(!jQuery(this).hasClass("button")) jQuery(this).val("");  
})//this is missing a ;
```

After that you can think properly on post method like Kevin Schmid said..

Answer (score -1):

The validator function check each input with `".requiredfield"` class.
Sample Code :

```
formid.find(".requiredfield").each(function () {
```